# In Spring 4, how do I define generic beans without explicitly specifying every possible type?

Tags: java, spring, generics

In Spring 4, it's possible to use generic types to distinguish between the types of beans. I've read the [basic documentation describing this feature](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics).

The problem is that (as far as I can tell) this requires an explicit bean definition for every possible generic type you might want to use. However, if there's a lot of different classes that can realistically be used here, that will become painful very quickly (and if it's a generic with two or three type parameters, imagine how quickly this could become unmanageable). An example:

```
@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingA> someGenericThingA(ThingA thingA) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingA);
}

@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingB> someGenericThingB(ThingB thingB) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingB);
}

@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingC> someGenericThingC(ThingC thingC) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingC);
}

@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingD> someGenericThingD(ThingD thingD) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingD);
}

@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingE> someGenericThingE(ThingE thingE) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingE);
}

@Bean
public SomeGeneric<ThingF> someGenericThingF(ThingF thingF) {
  return new SomeGeneric<>(thingF);
}
```

Once the above is set up, I can very conveniently autowire any of these instances, as in the following:

```
@Autowired
SomeGeneric<ThingC> someGenericThingC;
```

But because this is such a mindless, repetitive pattern, I was wondering whether there is some way to avoid all this repetition in the configuration class. Could I use some kind of Bean Factory or postprocessor to reduce this repetition?

Comment: You might try with an interface and some implementations of it.

Comment: @Alfabravo That's kind of vague, isn't it? And I don't see how adding one or more interfaces would change the situation.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Box` here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is a minimal, trivial example of the structure I'm working with. "Box" stands for basically any generic. My actual code gives Box its own functionality beyond exposing a contained item. I thought this question was big enough without trying to cram in all the irrelevant details that justified the design in the first place.

Comment: Right, but you know it doesn't work. So let's try to fix the actual issue. This sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know it doesn't work. I expect there to be a solution, as I wrote in my question. Thank you for the obligatory suggestion that this is an XY problem; I know a StackOverflow question about anything non-trivial would be incomplete without it.

Comment: Spring can initialize and provide objects using factory for you. Are ThingA and ThingB product of the same Box family and aren't you trying to initialize beans/objects depending upon a type passed (and you are using generics for it)? If this meets your  design, I can share some examples.

Comment: @Stacky I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if they are "product of the same Box family." They are not ancestor/descendant classes. Yes, I am trying to initialize these based on the type passed, which is why the constructors are the way they are. I was hoping those initializing parameters could be instantiated from the type parameter information.

Comment: I have modified the question to avoid the confusion caused by the extra classes I included for completeness.